# SingleValueEventListener do not get the value after button click

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get nickname value from Firebase Real time database after button is clicked. So i made `singleValueListner()` in button´s `onClick` method. But it don´t work.

I have tried debug it, but code didn´t get into `singleValueEventListener()`

```
Button getName = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getName);

getName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member").child(user.getUid());
        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                    tv.setText(data.child("nickname").getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Database JSON structure:

```
{
  "Member" : {
    "1Zuv6VZZ0kPluwc33f1QQQ7DZD93" /* UID */ : {
      "-LgIHwiAjfuh5pjK7wzl" : {
        "actualScore" : 0,
        "bestScore" : 0,
        "email" : "some@email.com",
        "nickname" : "Vitek",
        "season" : 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Database structure:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15B4b6Rb_WAiS6fioI9gItyijrbDiVjzJ/view

I need to get nickname, I think this is writen good, but not. So, what is wrong?

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: The first step would be to stop ignoring errors and implement `onCancelled`. Minimal implementation is: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen okey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of your `nickname` property, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Member").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String nickname = dataSnapshot.child("nickname").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, nickname);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
Vitek
```

So there is no need to loop through the `DataSnapshot` object in order to get the value of your `nickname` property. If you don't get this result, please check the logcat to see if you have an error message printed out.

Answer (score 0):

You are only referring up to user's id but there is also a parent key of user detail which you need to reference.

```
tv.setText(data.child("LgiH------").child("nickname").getValue().toString());
```

but try to remove that second key from your registering user's code because it is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake in refering your firebase root node. just change your line as below :

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Member");
```

Now,just call your singlevalue event.

```
db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
                    tv.setText(data.child("nickname").getValue().toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

This will do your stuff. try debugging your code with log at step by step.